# Polynomial LongDivision

Tags: polynomials

What would be the result of $x^3-4x^2-5$ divided by $x-3$ ? I am getting $4$ as my solution can someone prove me wrong, this is very confusing.

Comment: Do you mean you get a remainder of $4$? I get a remainder of $-5-9 = -14$. Are you getting $-5+9 = 4$? After division I get $$x^2-x-3-\frac{14}{3-x}$$

Comment: Try posting your work so we can take a look at it.

Comment: yes i was looking for he remainder

Comment: It seems difficult to tell where is your problem if you don't post your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder when dividing by $x-3$ is also the polynomial evaluated at $x=3$, which is $27-4\cdot 9-5=-14$.
Indeed,
$$\begin{align}x^3-4x^2-5&=x^2\cdot(x-3)-x^2-5\\&=(x^2-x)(x-3)-3x-5\\&=(x^2-x-3)(x-3)-14\end{align}$$

Comment: both you and my text book are right, but if i try to prove it using polynomial long division I get 4, if i use the remainder theorem my answer is -14. What am I doing wrong